# adding viewport in scrollview jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, viewport

im using https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview. I have a problem, At first everything works fine but when I added viewport: e.g. : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. It adjusted the fixed footer, it has now have a 5em padding bottom this is in portrait mode. Worst is in landscape mode the footer further adjusted to 10em. T_T.

I'm using an iphone4 vers. 4.3.3.

Hope anyone can help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to change to Jquery mobile 1.1.0 and their real fixed toolbars. [Read their announcement](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/). Its supported by most of the devices in use and the most clean solution:

> The coolest part about this approach is that, unlike JS-based solutions that impose the unnatural scrolling physics across all platforms, our scrolling feels 100% native because it *is*. This means that scrolling feels right everywhere and works with touch, mousewheel and keyboard user input. As a bonus, our CSS-based solution is super lightweight and doesn’t impact compatibility or accessibility.